# How to evenly distribute objects along an array so neighbours get equidistant?

Tags: algorithms

I have `R` objects, where `R >= 3`.

I have a N-sized array, where `N > R`.

I would like to determine in which indexes of the array I must put the `R` objects so the distance between any two neighbors will be equal, or the most similar possible.

Eg:

for `N = 4`, `R = 3`

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{o, o,  , o}
```

or

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{o,  , o, o}
```

for `N = 17`, `R = 10`

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
{o, o, o,  , o,  , o,  , o,   ,  o,   ,  o,   ,  o,   ,  o}
```

or

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
{o, o,  , o,  , o,  , o,  ,  o,   ,  o,   ,  o,   ,  o,  o}
```

Of course I need the objects to be the most distant possible form each other, so this is unacceptable:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
{o, o, o, o,  ,  ,  }

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
{o,  , o,  , o,  , o,  }
```

Basically the first and last position of the array will always be occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any `N >= 2`, `R >= 2` and `N >= R`:

```
static boolean[] findIndexes(int n, int r) {
    boolean[] arrayWithObjects = new boolean[n];

    int quotient = (n-1) / (r-1);
    int remainder = (n-1) % (r-1);

    int index = 0;
    do {
        arrayWithObjects[index] = true;
    } while( (index += quotient + (remainder-- > 0 ? 1 : 0)) < n );

    return arrayWithObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the 0th element at index 0, the R-1th element at index N-1.

Calculate `d = floor(N / R)`.

This function describes the target indexes for the 1st to the R-2th element: `i(x) = 2 * d * x`;

Examles:

```
R=3,N=4
{0, 1, 2, 3}
{o,  , o, o}

R=7 N=12
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11}
{o,  , o,  , o,  , o,  , o,  , o, o}
```

Comment: I don't think d will ever be 0. There is no Rth element. In the example R=7 N=12, the indexes will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11. Did you mean `d=round(N/R)`?

Comment: @Gustavo you said `N > R` is always true.  When would it ever matter?  We prefer floor because integer division gives it to us for free.

Comment: @marstato d shouldn't ever be 0. If it was every element would pile up in the same index: 0.  i(x) = d*x right?  `N>R` means the lowest `floor(N / R)`  will ever be is 1.  Which is fine.  `d==1` maps each to it's previous position.

Comment: You guys are all correcr. I updated the answer

Comment: It fascinates me how much this problem resembles [a line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm)

Comment: @marstato Try N = 6 and R = 3. You will get this `{o, , , , o, o}`.